# Oracle create user with privileges to grant references

Tags: oracle, permissions

I want to create an Oracle user who can grant references to other users.
Do I need to make him `sysdba` for that, or is there any other way?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e10592/statements_9013.htm check it....

Answer (score 9):

You don't need to grant `SYSDBA` privileges, and shouldn't unless really necessary. You should follow the [principle of least privilege](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_privilege). From Oracle's [security guidelines](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/network.112/e16543/guidelines.htm#autoId4):

> Do not provide database users or roles more privileges than are
>   necessary. (If possible, grant privileges to roles, not users.) In
>   other words, *the principle of least privilege* is that users be given
>   only those privileges that are actually required to efficiently
>   perform their jobs.

You just need to grant [with admin option](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e10592/statements_9013.htm#SQLRF55020):

```
grant references on <schema>.<table> to <user> with admin option;
```

`<user>` can then grant references on to others, but can't pass on the admin option.